# Create a new Pandas DF from existing DF based on the contents of the first point

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new data frame based on the contents of another data frame.
Essentially I am importing a CSV file as a pivot_table but I then want to split it out into several separate Dataframes and with the option to export to other CSVs or JSON

The contents is basically

```
Region,Name,utilization,capacity
North,Westfield,10,20
North,ShadyAcres,100,300
South,Chapelton,30,300
South,Spinney,10,40
Midlands,oakfields,10,15
Midlands,chestfords,14,20
```

I basically want to strip it down to so that I have separate data frames that only contain

```
Name,Utilization,Capacity
```

Based on the Region column,I tried

```
df.[northregion] = df.region == 'North'
```

While that did identify the regions based on the contents, when I created the new data frame

```
north = df.pivot_table(index['northregion] etc...
```

It just inserts a True False into the entire Frame instead

Comment: Use `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Region')))`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df_Region={i:group for i,group in df.groupby('Region')}
```

or as Jezrael suggested:

```
df_Region=dict(tuple(df.groupby('Region')))
```

---

```
for Region in df_Region:
    print(f'df[{Region}]')
    print(df_Region[Region])
    print('-'*50)


df[Midlands]
     Region        Name  utilization  capacity
4  Midlands   oakfields           10        15
5  Midlands  chestfords           14        20
--------------------------------------------------
df[North]
  Region        Name  utilization  capacity
0  North   Westfield           10        20
1  North  ShadyAcres          100       300
--------------------------------------------------
df[South]
  Region       Name  utilization  capacity
2  South  Chapelton           30       300
3  South    Spinney           10        40
--------------------------------------------------
```

this creates a DataFrame dictionary that is accessed by the value of the `Region` column

---

to create a specific dataframe you could do:

```
df[df['Region']=='North']
```

Comment: Quite smart, creating dictionary of dataframes, I like it :)